# su and passwd : Authentication error

Tags: linux, su, passwd

I had a strange behaviour with `su -` command. In fact I can't use `/usr/bin/su -` to get to root account. I use sudo which works perfectly but some other users, also in sudoers, are able to change sudo files and can break the syntax. That's why I need the `su`.

When I connect with SSH to the server, everything runs well. When typing `su -`, the password is asked and then I get the following :

```
[connect_user@serveur ~]$ su -
Password:
su: Permission denied
[connect_user@serveur ~]$
```

So I go with `sudo -i` to see log files.

/var/log/secure :
`su[223912]: pam_succeed_if(su-l:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"`

/var/log/messages :
`su[223912]: FAILED SU (to root) connect_user on pts/0`

/var/log/audit/audit.log : Does not contain any information about what just happen.

I had the stickybit missing on `/usr/bin/su` but no more errors. The PAM is set by default with all defaults options, no change on it.

What's anoying now is the `passwd` also failling ...

```
[connect_user@serveur~]$ passwd
Changing password for user connect_user.
Changing password for connect_user.
(current) UNIX password:
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
[connect_user@serveur~]$
```

At this point I'm a bit lost as I thought it was only `su` in error. Another server, deployed like the first one, is working as expected, which means they're not exaclty the same as they are supposed to be.

---

Infos :

Server is a CentOS 7

SeLinux was enabled but is now disabled

User minimum ID is set to 1001